# ClassCastException in list implementation?

Tags: java, list, adt, classcastexception

I am trying to implement a list ADT in Java.I followed a book on Data Structures by Goodrich.

I created 2 interfaces called Position:

```
public interface Position {
    Object element()throws InvalidPositionException;

}
```

and List which has method declaration of lists like `first(), last()`, etc.

Now, i have a class called DNode.java which implements Position and has methods to assign the previous and next elements for a particular node.

And finally, I have NodeList.java which implements the List interface.

In this, there is a `insertBefore()` method that takes Position and Object as input and makes changes to the list to insert the node before a particular position.

Now, this method is called from the ListMain class which is the main class.

```
    Object p = (Object) br.readLine();
    nl.insertAfter((Position)p, element);
    nl.display();
```

Basically, I have taken an input from the user in the form of a string, converted it to type Object and then converted it to type Position.
When I do so, I get a class cast exception that says

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to ListPackage.Position

Can someone please tell me how to do the appropriate type casting. Or is my approach wrong and should I be doing something else?

I am new to data structures. So, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is `br`? If that's a BufferedReader, then obviously you read String, and it can't be casted to a `Position`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says you are trying to say that a `String` is a `Position`, which it is not.  Instead you need to create a `Position` from the `String`:

```
String s = br.readLine();
Position p = new DNode(s);
```

And you will have to implement the logic of how to convert a `String` into a `DNode` object in the `DNode` class's constructor

Comment: I created a constructor in DNode that took string as parameter. But I am not able to set the prev and next fields to anything other than null (which I do not want). What should I do?

Comment: You need to add the prev/next links externally by calling say a `setNext()`/`setPrev()` method.  Who is doing the calling is another question: you could do it directly from `main()`, but since you have a `NodeList` class already, you could call its `insertNode()` method.  If you do the latter, you can specify the position via an index or an Iterator (if your List supports that) -- it's up to you, based on what makes sense (see if there is anything similar in the `List` interface already; if yes, implement/use that method)

Answer (score 3):

You can't arbitrarily cast objects to other types in all cases.  Consider writing a constructor for `Position` that takes the string value(s) the user provides as parameters.